# Android ListFragment with Custom image checkbox

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android, android-listfragment

I am using a Listfragment which has a checkbox with custom images that changes on state_checked. 
 But 'onListItemClick' function works only when checkbox is assigned to android:focusable="false" and  android:clickable="false" in its layout.

In this case the custom image change of checkbox is not working.
Is there a way to accomplish both together.Any help is appreciated.

```
public class SympFragment extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener {
private ListView lv;
private String listview_array[] = {
        "Text1",
        "Text2",
        "Text3",
        "Text4",
};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_symp, container, false);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.ch_row, listview_array);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch( position )
    {
        case 0:    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Well Done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

    }
}
```

}

Layout:

```
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/chcheckbox"
     android:textSize="15sp"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:button="@drawable/chselector"
     android:drawableLeft="@android:color/transparent"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:clickable="false"
     android:padding="8dp"
  />
```

Selector xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like 'onListItemClick' never accepts checkbox input. So the checkbox has to be setted to  android:focusable="false" and android:clickable="false".
But checkbox can be triggered by the following way :

```
    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    CheckBox chcheckbox;
    switch(position){
        case 0:

            chcheckbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chcheckbox);
            if (chcheckbox.isChecked() == false) {
                chcheckbox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                chcheckbox.setChecked(false);
            } break;

        case 1:

            chcheckbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chcheckbox);
            if (chcheckbox.isChecked() == false) {
                chcheckbox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                chcheckbox.setChecked(false);
            } break;
    }

}
```

Am not sure whether this is a best practice. But this tweak is much useful as I didn't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

create xml file custom_checkbox.xml in drawable :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected"/>    
</selector>
```

and in checkbox call :

```
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
```

Comment: no..its still not working. The onListItemClickListener works only when I set the focusable and clickable of checkbox to false. If I do so..the selector is not working. I have attached the coding part now.